# Can I Set the Country in Bogus (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, country, bogus

I've just started working with Bogus in C# .net 5.0.
I am managing to return very usable data in a sandbox app but I want to restrict the the data to be USA based. Is there a way to do this? (here's part of my sandbox app)

```
using Bogus;

namespace FrankenPeople
{
    public class GetBogus
    {
        public enum Gender
        {
            Male,
            Female
        }

        private static int userId = 1;

        private static readonly Faker<Person> fakeData = new Faker<Person>()
            .RuleFor(p => p.Id, f => userId++)
            .RuleFor(p => p.Gender, f => f.PickRandom<Gender>().ToString())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Title, f => f.Name.Prefix(f.Person.Gender))
            .RuleFor(p => p.FirstName, f => f.Name.FirstName(f.Person.Gender))
            .RuleFor(p => p.MiddleName, f => f.Name.FirstName(f.Person.Gender))
            .RuleFor(p => p.LastName, f => f.Name.LastName(f.Person.Gender))
            .RuleFor(p => p.StreetAddress, f => f.Address.StreetAddress())
            .RuleFor(p => p.StreetName, f => f.Address.StreetName())
            .RuleFor(p => p.City, f => f.Address.City())
            .RuleFor(p => p.State, f => f.Address.State())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Country, f => f.Address.Country())
            .RuleFor(p => p.ZipCode, f => f.Address.ZipCode())
            .RuleFor(p => p.Phone, f => f.Phone.PhoneNumber("(###)-###-####"))
            .RuleFor(p => p.Email, (f, p) => f.Internet.Email(p.FirstName, p.LastName))
            .RuleFor(p => p.SSN, f => f.Random.Replace("###-##-####"))
            .RuleFor(p => p.DOB, f => f.Date.Past(18))
        ;
        public static Faker<Person> FakeData => fakeData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: Im using the NuGet package Bogus to generate fake data.

Comment: Hi Robert. I added my sandbox app (but not the person class which declares all of the properties.) If you notice the line
 .RuleFor(p => p.Country, f => f.Address.Country())
that's where the Country comes from.

The data returned contains like this but I need to constrain the results to only USA.

    "Country": "Nepal",

Comment: It says you can set a locale in Bogus.  Have you tried setting `en_US`?

Comment: What do you mean you want the data to be USA based?
setting the Locale to en_US will set things the addresses, domain suffixes and phone numbers.

Comment: How do I set the Locale to en-US? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Using locales](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus#locales) you can get addresses, domain suffixes and phone numbers:

```cs
var faker = new Faker("en_US");
```

Comment: Thank you Alenros. I hadn't considered putting the country in the constructor. Everything is good now.

Answer (score 3):

By default, **Bogus** uses the `en` locale which is *roughly* USA based. If you want to lock things down as much as possible to USA, then use the `en_US` locale.

Specifically, in your code example, to specify a locale other than the default, change:

```cs
fakeData = new Faker<Person>()   //default is `en`
             ...
```

to

```cs
fakeData = new Faker<Person>(locale: "en_US")
             ...
```

Locales are not 100% perfect, please be sure to read the small note in this section of the README file: https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus#locales

> ***Note:*** Some locales may not have a complete data set. For example, [`zh_CN`](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/tree/master/lib/locales/zh_CN) does not have a `lorem` data set, but [`ko`](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/tree/master/lib/locales/ko) has a `lorem` data set. **Bogus** will default to `en` if a *locale-specific* data set is not found. To further illustrate the previous example, the missing `zh_CN:lorem` data set will default to the `en:lorem` data set.