# How to change the format of test dates generated by Bogus in C#

Tags: c#, .net, faker, bogus

I'd like to format the test dates generated by Bogus to `dd.MM.yyyy` (eg. 29.09.2022).

I've been searching for a solution but can't find anything.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var personData = new Faker<Person>()
    .RuleFor(
        p => p.DateOfBirth,
        f => f.Date.Past(30, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20))
        .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65943152/7565574 has a similar issue: so try `new Faker<Person>("de_DE");` or `new Faker<Person>("de");`

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```
.RuleFor(c => c.Birthday, f =>
                         {
                             var pastDateTime = f.Date.PastOffset(40, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18));
                             var result = DateTime.Parse(pastDateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
                             return result;
                         })
```

enjoy it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).